# Can you call sendTo() multiple times in a select() block?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am using Linux call `select()` to see if a *non-blocking* UDP socket is writable. I am sending to multiple IP addresses. My question is, can you actually do all your sendTo()'s within a select() block, or do you need to write and then check select again before the next sendTo call, for every one?

Example:

```
struct timeval tv;
fd_set write_fds;
int ready;
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
FD_ZERO(&write_fds);
FD_SET((sock_fd), &write_fds);

ready = select((sock_fd) + 1, NULL, &write_fds, NULL, &tv);

// check if socket is WRITABLE
if ( ready && FD_ISSET((sock_fd), &write_fds) ) 
{
    // Send data to ADDRESS 1
    sendto(sock_fd, Msg, len, 0, 
                  (struct sockaddr*)&C1Remoteaddr, sizeof (C1Remoteaddr));

    // Send data to ADDRESS 2
    sendto(sock_fd, Msg, len, 0, 
          (struct sockaddr*)&C2Remoteaddr, sizeof (C2Remoteaddr));

}
```

Or, do I have to do this:

```
ready = select((sock_fd) + 1, NULL, &write_fds, NULL, &tv);

// check if socket is WRITABLE
if ( ready && FD_ISSET((sock_fd), &write_fds) ) 
{
    // Send data to ADDRESS 1
    sendto(sock_fd, Msg, len, 0, 
              (struct sockaddr*)&C1Remoteaddr, sizeof (C1Remoteaddr));

    // Reset FD Status?
    FD_ZERO(&write_fds);
    FD_SET((sock_fd), &write_fds);

    ready = select((sock_fd) + 1, NULL, &write_fds, NULL, &tv);
    if ( ready && FD_ISSET((sock_fd), &write_fds) ) 
    {
        // Send data to ADDRESS 2
        sendto(sock_fd, Msg, len, 0, 
              (struct sockaddr*)&C2Remoteaddr, sizeof (C2Remoteaddr));
    }
}
```

I have an array of addresses I need to write to, so I want to make sure I understand this correctly.

Comment: UDP is connectionless, so testing a UDP socket for writability is usually not necessary at all.  But if you want to, sure, go for it.  You can call `sendto()` as many times as you want, and it will simply fail with an error code if it will end up blocking a non-blocking socket. You have to pay attention to the return value!  If `sendto()` tells you the socket will block, stop sending, and retry your remaining data only after `select()` tells you it is OK to try again.

Comment: Also, `if ( ready && .. )` is wrong, since `select()` *can* return `-1`, which would also satisfy the `if` (*any* non-zero value would).  Use `if( (ready > 0) && ... )` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `sendto()` whenever you like, not just when `select()` tells you the socket is writable. It's when `sendto()` induces EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK that you need to pay attention to what `select()` tells you.